# Django Joining multiple tables

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm working with an e-commerce website. I need to add multiple variations for a single product. ie.  A shirt can be of multiple color and size.

My models goes Here :

```
Class Product (models.Model):
     product_name= models.CharField(max_length=150)
     ..
     ..
     ..

     def __str__(self):
          return self.product_name



class Color(models.Model):
     product = models.Forignkey(Product, on_ delete = models.CASCADE)
     color_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     ..
     ..
     ..

     def __str__(self):
          return f'{self.product.product_name} |{self.color_name}'



class Size(models.Model):
     product = models.Forignkey(Product, on_ delete = models.CASCADE)
     size_letter = models.CharField(max_length=150)
     ..
     ..
     ..

     def __str__(self):
          return f'{self.product.product_name} | {self.size_letter}




class Productimage(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete = models. CASCADE)
     image_1 = models.ImageField(default ='product.jpg', upload_to ='product_images')
     ..
     ..
     ..

     def __str__(self):
          return f'{self.product.product_name} - images'
```

And my view

```
Class ProductDetailView(ListView):
     template_name = 'customer/product_detail.html'
     model = Product
```

How can I access all products on single page?? With its images on the template . I need to access to all of the above table while querying only to the Product table.

I tried with

```
Product.objects.filter(productimage__product=1)
```

But this returns a singl row.. i need all objects

I thinks its a kind of joining these tables using product_id.

But idk how to join these tables.

Really need help.. I'm stuck ..!!

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you have an image of all products in the `ProductImage` model?

Comment: What you're doing is joining the table `Productimage` and filtering by product_id = 1, which would be the same as `Product.objects.filter(id=1).prefetch_related("productimage")`

Answer (score 0):

To get all products:

```
Product.objects.all()
```

Also with additional details:

```
Product.objects.all().prefetch_related('colors', 'sizes', 'productimage')
```